# Python: covert geopandas centroid to latitude/longitude coordinates?

Tags: python, geolocation, geometry, geospatial, geopandas

I am trying to get the lat/lon coordinates of the center of NY counties. The shapefile I'm using is available [here](http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=927). I calculated the centroids of each county, and added a new centroids column, with the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
counties = gpd.read_file("Counties.shp")
counties["center"] = counties["geometry"].centroid
```

I initially thought the centroids returned would be lat/long coordinates, but here's an example of one of the points in the column:

POINT (584193.731 4716921.695)

How would I go about converting this point to valid, corresponding latitude and longitude coordinates? Is there an easy way to do this with python libraries?

Comment: The last line of code should be `counties["center"]=counties["geometry"].centroid.to_crs(epsg=4326)`

Comment: @swatchai This code returned the following warning:                        ```t<ipython-input-22-3b1a11c5ec66>:1: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.```

Comment: It will be `incorrect` only when the locations is at high distortion area of the projection in use. If you plot them and check with the polygons they belong to, you can verify that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the particular shapefile I was using. [Here](https://cugir.library.cornell.edu/catalog/cugir-007865) is a NY counties shapefile whose geometry centroids are valid lat/lon coordinates.